# Soundcloud JAVA api wrapper : SSLException

Tags: java, ssl, soundcloud

When using the soundcloud [JAVA wrapper for the API](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper)

i get the following SSL error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: 
api.soundcloud.com/178.249.136.151 != api.soundcloud.com OR api.soundcloud.com
```

I am using java-api-wrapper-1.1.2-all.jar

Found a google group post saying using the jar with everything bundled (..-all.jar) fixed the issue, but apparently not for me..

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem,

Conflicting jars for org apache httpclient, removed 4.1.2 and left 4.1.1, witch solved the issue.