# Soundcloud JAVA api wrapper : SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: java, ssl, soundcloud

When using the soundcloud JAVA wrapper for the API,

```
ApiWrapper wrapper = new ApiWrapper("id","secret", null, null, Env.SANDBOX);
try {
    wrapper.login("user", "pw"); // fail here
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get the following SSL exception error:

```
SSLPeerUnverifiedException
```

The full exception details:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:399)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:597)
at com.soundcloud.api.ApiWrapper.safeExecute(ApiWrapper.java:550)
at com.soundcloud.api.ApiWrapper.requestToken(ApiWrapper.java:266)
at com.soundcloud.api.ApiWrapper.login(ApiWrapper.java:143)
at de.voidplus.soundcloud.Sketch.setup(Sketch.java:23)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2103)
at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:190)
at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2006)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I used the `java-api-wrapper-1.1.2-all.jar` for all dependencies. I compiled it with Java 1.6. I'm using the [processing](http://www.processing.org) core library, too, but it should not be the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using Env.LIVE?

Env.Live is using http://sandbox-soundcloud.com instead of the main-site.

just one thought.

Have you already looked at this one: [Soundcloud JAVA api wrapper : SSLException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093412/soundcloud-java-api-wrapper-sslexception)?

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot! I'm learning the library by the way ... so I didn't know, that the LIVE mode is important. And yes, I saw the thread before. Now, I delete all the manual classes of JSON plus Apache and I'm using the java-api-wrapper-1.1.2-all.jar without trouble.

Comment: Env.SANDBOX is now deprecated - version 1.2.0 of the wrapper defaults to the live environment.

Comment: how to import java-wrapper-api in android project.its a git project its not a library and could not import into my project.